# How do I modify a button from a function in Google Apps Script UI App

Tags: forms, google-apps-script

I have created a UI App Form Panel in Google Apps Script with the following following button definition:

```
  var voteButton = app.createButton('Submit');
  var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('buttonPressed');
  handler.addCallbackElement(formContent);
  voteButton.addClickHandler(handler);
```

the severClickHandler is set to call the following function:

```
buttonPressed(){
   //do something .....
}
```

This works well, but I need to disable the voteButton once the execution og the buttonPressed() function is completed successfully. How can set voteButton to not visible. Is there a way I can pass the vote button to the buttonPressed function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jesse, over at the Google App Script forum, has answered this question:
[Server Click Handler](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/apps-script/thread?tid=5c6cfed2110cf52e&hl=en)